# Playing a video hosted on a cloud server?

Tags: hosting, webserver, cloud, shared-hosting, cloud-hosting

If I have a website hosted on a shared server (e.g. Just Host), but I have a HD movie on my site hosted on a cloud server (e.g. Rackspace), will the movie be using the shared or the cloud server if I were to allow users to stream the movie using HTML5 video? Technically the page they'll be viewing the video on, will be hosted on the Shared server, but the HTML5 video link will point to the URL of the video hosted on the cloud server, so I wondered whether streaming the movie like this will affect the bandwidth of the Shared Host?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> whether streaming the movie like this will affect the bandwidth of the
>   Shared Host?

Nope, web browser will open separate connection to your rackspace server. You can verify this by your browser debug tools (like firebug for firefox) or even by network packet analyzer (wireshark for example).

Lots of sites are doing this by hosting images and videos on various [CDNs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network).